# phpbrew and php-4.4.9: is it possible?

Tags: php, apache

For some old code I need to reconfigure a test server with PHP 4.4 for Apache2.

I have used phpbrew so far to do version switching. Anyhow I don't get PHP4-versions displayed when fetching the release list.

```
# phpbrew known --old --update
===> Fetching release list...
5.6: 5.6.2, 5.6.1, 5.6.0 ...
5.5: 5.5.18, 5.5.17, 5.5.16, 5.5.15, 5.5.14, 5.5.13, 5.5.12, 5.5.11 ...
5.4: 5.4.34, 5.4.33, 5.4.32, 5.4.31, 5.4.30, 5.4.29, 5.4.28, 5.4.27 ...
5.3: 5.3.29, 5.3.28, 5.3.27, 5.3.26, 5.3.25, 5.3.24, 5.3.23, 5.3.22 ...
5.2: 5.2.17, 5.2.16, 5.2.15, 5.2.14, 5.2.13, 5.2.12, 5.2.11, 5.2.10 ...
```

Is compiling PHP 4.4 with phpbrew possible?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This was intended a comment.

=============================

If it would be possible, the command would be:

```
# phpbrew known --old -update
```

But I don't think PHP 4.4 is still in PHPBREW

Comment: This is not an answer, merely a comment

Comment: true. Did it wrong, deletion is not an option I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't know why not ;) Just delete it and add it in a comment (as it isn't useless what you're saying!), easy does it ;)